# How to pass multiple parameters and a function and then execute function with parameters in Java 8?

Tags: java, function, generics, lambda, java-8

We have this school project where we should make rent-a-car-like java app.

I wrote the following code that just takes some jsonObject properties, calls function depending on the action code and puts some things in jsonObject property. But I reaaally don't like this code repetition pattern...

```
if(action.equals("REGOPR")) {
    // Register operator
    String user = (String)jsonObject.get("username");
    String pass = (String)jsonObject.get("password");
    if(registerOperator(user, pass))
        jsonObj.put("resp", "Operator successfully registered!");
    else {
        jsonObj.put("status", "fail");
        jsonObj.put("resp", "Username already taken!");
    }
} else if (action.equals("ADDVEH")) {
    // Add vehicle
    String manuf = (String)jsonObject.get("manufacturer");
    String regis = (String)jsonObject.get("registration");
    String licen =((String)jsonObject.get("license"));
    if(addVehicle(manuf, regis, licen))
        jsonObj.put("resp", "Successfully added vehicle!");
    else {
        jsonObj.put("status", "fail");
        jsonObj.put("resp", "Vehicle alredy exists!");
    }
}  And fifteeen more else ifs with different "actions"...
```

What I would like to do instead is something like this

```
if(action.equals("REGOPR")){
     awesomeMethod(registerOperator, 
                  "Custom succesffull message", 
                  "Fail message", 
                  "username", 
                  "password");
} else if(action.equals("ADDVEH")) {
    awesomeMethod(addVehicle, 
                  "Custom succesfull message 2", 
                  "Fail message 2", 
                  "manufacturer", 
                  "registration", 
                  "license");
}
```

So arbitrary number of Strings at the end and for each it should grab the value from json and just feed it into the given function.

Comment: I think you can use this on the `awesomeMethod(String... obj)`, this basically tells `awesomeMethod()` that he will receive one or more parameters. When using `Object... obj` you should put it always at the end. e.g.: `method(String one, String two, String... three)`.

Comment: @Julian Yes. But that will only pass the names of the parameters. How can I call functions later on with newly extracted params?

Comment: Have you considered a more polymorphic approach? Maybe use a HashMap of interfaces instead of a 15+ switch statement?

Comment: @Johannes Can you expand on that a bit more? I got a bit rusty on Java these days. :D

Comment: Maybe that can help you:http://refactoring.com/catalog/replaceConditionalWithPolymorphism.html

Comment: @Johannes Yes but you see, this is actually server-client protocol and action to be performed is extracted from json-received string. So I don't think I can avoid else-ifs, can I?

Comment: You can. I can give you an example, but comments aren't made for code examples. is there something like codepen for java?

Comment: @Johannes [Ideone](https://ideone.com/) is commonly used.

Comment: Thanks Jorn.
http://ideone.com/FqIYPe 
It won't compile because i'm too lazy but maybe you can grasp the idea

Answer (score 3):

Since the method signatures are incompatible (let's not try to change those), you would have to box into an array:

```
private void awesomeMethod(Predicate<String[]> func, String failMessage,
        String succesMessage, String...arr) {       
    String[] args = new String[arr.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
        args[i] = (String) jsonObject.get(arr[i]);

    if(func.test(args)) {
        jsonObj.put("resp", succesMessage);
    } else {
        jsonObj.put("status", "fail");
        jsonObj.put("resp", failMessage);
    }
}
```

Then, when calling, you have to map array positions to arguments:

```
awesomeMethod(arr -> addVehicle(arr[0], arr[1], arr[2]), 
              "Custom succesfull message 2", 
              "Fail message 2", 
              "manufacturer", 
              "registration", 
              "license");
```

---

If you only have methods with few differing numbers of parameters, you could also consider making overloads for each number of parameters. That will avoid the array boxing, and make the call simpler.

You could also get rid of the if statements by using a map.

Comment: This assumes `jsonObject` and `jsonObj` are not local variables.

Comment: @shmosel Yes, just like OP did in the example use of `awesomeMethod`

Comment: He could simply add them to the parameters of that awesomeMethod, the answer is still vaild

Comment: @JornVernee OP's example is obviously hypothetical. It doesn't necessarily reflect what's possible.

Comment: @Johannes, agreed. Though it's not quite as awesome anymore. I was actually writing the exact same answer with that minor difference, but this will do.

Comment: @shmosel I know that feel bro

Comment: @Jornvernee You are right. I forgot to pass both of them!